# ASP.Net get line number in source file

Tags: asp.net

I would like to send with the Trace.TraceWarning also a line number stating where it came from in the source files. is there a Macro/Define for that in 3.5?

Thanks,

Teddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int s = GetLine();
    Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
}

static int GetLine()
{
    StackFrame stackFrame = new StackFrame(1, true);
    return stackFrame.GetFileLineNumber();
}
```

Comment: I think this gets the starting line at the time this frame was pushed on the stack.  Execution has probably advanced some since then.  That said, I suppose if you're keeping your methods nice and short it's not hard to know how big of an offset to add manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I don't think so.  *If* it's anywhere, it's in the stacktrace, and you can get that like this:

```
var st = new  StackTrace(true);
```